# postgreSQL: what is pga4_session cookie?

Tags: postgresql, session, cookies, session-cookies, pgadmin

I am developing the backend with nest, the DB with postgreSQL, and the frontend with next.

It seems to be a session related to postgreSQL. Why did pga4_session occur?
I can't trace what caused this session.
It probably occurred after the frontend called the API that CRUDs the DB on the backend.
Are there any security or performance issues?

Comment: pga4_session is the cookiename set by pgadmin... you should not reach pgadmin in your case? Why are you connecting through pgadmin?

Comment: You didn't share a lot of information, but it's kind of worrisome that something like pga4_session pops up in your database when connecting your API to the database server. pgAdmin is just one of many PostgreSQL clients and has nothing to do with an API. Something is odd. Could you share some information about your architecture?

Comment: I use pgadmin in localhost:5050. Frontend and Backend use localhost:3xxx. I use pgadmin before, and i forgot it. Maybe it made cookie. I think it is just happening.